# Case statements in my sql select statement

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
column1,
column2,
(CASE WHEN column1=NULL THEN @NEW_column =column2
WHEN column1!=NULL THEN @NEW_column =column1
END) AS NEW_column,
FROM my_table
```

In the above select statement , i am creating a new variable called
 NEW_column and the value of it should be based on the conditions in case statement.
When i run this query value is "NEW_column" is returned as NULL. Can anyone help me solve this logical error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `column1 is null` similarly `column1 is not null`

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uk1TEXUAUEznGJxbHhAPsG/0)**

```
SELECT
   column1,
   column2,
   CASE WHEN column1 is NULL THEN column2
   WHEN column1 is not NULL THEN column1
   END AS NEW_column,
FROM my_table
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1    col2    newcol
3       null    3
null    4       4
5      null     5
```

Comment: NEW_column is still returned with the NULL.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data in your question - then it will easy to understand what actually wrong @BhavanaDixit

Comment: two of the columns in my table are column1 and column2. The case is either column1 and column2 will be null in each record ( column1 and column2 cant be null simultaneously in the record )  . I want to compute a new_column where it picks the value either from column1 or column2 which are not null.

Comment: @BhavanaDixit - check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9815ebf083af77a20bc6cd70f5cc948c

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't get any value with your conditions

There are several way to debug the your SQL statement:

sample

```
SELECT
column1,
column2,
ISNULL(column1,column2) AS NEW_column 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: The ISNULL() function returns 1 or 0 depending on whether an expression is NULL - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_isnull.asp

Comment: you can set string as default value. or use COALESCE()